# Saving a text file from flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, text

Quick question - i am wishing to produce an offline high score system for a pinball game i am creating, that stores the 10 highest scores in a text document. I have no idea how to do this - so any help is greatly appreciated - I am using AS3 with flash, and if it's possible please make the answer as basic to understand as i am still doing very basic programming in Flash at this given moment,

I currently have not tried anything yet as i have no idea where to start...

thanks,
Sam.

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/package-detail.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to write to a text file (have write access to your file system) you would need to publish your project as AIR application. I recommend you to use the SharedObject class for storing your data instead. You can for instance read and write an array with the scores easily, so no parsing is required.

```
        var scores : Array        = new Array(10,20,30);
        var my_so  : SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("myGameHighscore");
        my_so.data.scores         = scores; // set scores var to data object of SharedObject
        my_so.flush();            // writes the data instantly

        // To retreive your scores simply use getLocal again and then do something like:
        trace(my_so.data.scores[0]); // will trace first element of scores array "10"
```

Refer to http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html